# My animation Works only in Chrome and Safari but not IE or Firefox

Tags: css, animation

I added all the prefixes and still not working ?
It is like a slideshow that uses css to change the background to different images.
I don't understand what the problem is I looked everything over like 100 times.
You can see it on http://steveedwin.com/

```
html{
max-width:1000px;
}
#slideshow{

background-image: url('1.jpg') ;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size: 70% 350px;
width:100%;
height: 300px;
animation:myfirst 30s linear 1s infinite alternate;
/* Firefox: */
-moz-animation:myfirst 30s linear 1s infinite alternate;
/* Safari and Chrome: */
-webkit-animation:myfirst 30s linear 1s infinite alternate;
/* Opera: */
-o-animation:myfirst 30s linear 1s infinite alternate;
}
@keyframes myfirst
{
0% {background-image:url('1.jpg');}
5%{background-image:url('1.jpg');}
10%{background-image:url('1.jpg');}
15%{background-image:url('1.jpg');}
20%{background-image:url('5.jpg');}
25%{background-image:url('5.jpg');}
30%{background-image:url('5.jpg');}
40%{background-image:url('5.jpg');}
45%{background-image:url('2.jpg'); }
50%{background-image:url('2.jpg'); }
55%{background-image:url('2.jpg'); }
60%{background-image:url('2.jpg'); }
70%{background-image:url('3.jpg');}
75%{background-image:url('3.jpg');}
80%{background-image:url('3.jpg');}
85%{background-image:url('4.jpg');}
90%{background-image:url('4.jpg');}
95%{background-image:url('4.jpg');}
100%{background-image:url('4.jpg');}
}

@-moz-keyframes myfirst /* Firefox */
{
0% {background-image:url('1.jpg');}
5%{background-image:url('1.jpg');}
10%{background-image:url('1.jpg');}
15%{background-image:url('1.jpg');}
20%{background-image:url('5.jpg');}
25%{background-image:url('5.jpg');}
30%{background-image:url('5.jpg');}
40%{background-image:url('5.jpg');}
45%{background-image:url('2.jpg'); }
50%{background-image:url('2.jpg'); }
55%{background-image:url('2.jpg'); }
60%{background-image:url('2.jpg'); }
70%{background-image:url('3.jpg');}
75%{background-image:url('3.jpg');}
80%{background-image:url('3.jpg');}
85%{background-image:url('4.jpg');}
90%{background-image:url('4.jpg');}
95%{background-image:url('4.jpg');}
100%{background-image:url('4.jpg');}
}

@-webkit-keyframes myfirst /* Safari and Chrome */
{
0% {background-image:url('1.jpg');}
5%{background-image:url('1.jpg');}
10%{background-image:url('1.jpg');}
15%{background-image:url('1.jpg');}
20%{background-image:url('5.jpg');}
25%{background-image:url('5.jpg');}
30%{background-image:url('5.jpg');}
40%{background-image:url('5.jpg');}
45%{background-image:url('2.jpg'); }
50%{background-image:url('2.jpg'); }
55%{background-image:url('2.jpg'); }
60%{background-image:url('2.jpg'); }
70%{background-image:url('3.jpg');}
75%{background-image:url('3.jpg');}
80%{background-image:url('3.jpg');}
85%{background-image:url('4.jpg');}
90%{background-image:url('4.jpg');}
95%{background-image:url('4.jpg');}
100%{background-image:url('4.jpg');}
}

@-o-keyframes myfirst /* Opera */
{
0% {background-image:url('1.jpg');}
5%{background-image:url('1.jpg');}
10%{background-image:url('1.jpg');}
15%{background-image:url('1.jpg');}
20%{background-image:url('5.jpg');}
25%{background-image:url('5.jpg');}
30%{background-image:url('5.jpg');}
40%{background-image:url('5.jpg');}
45%{background-image:url('2.jpg'); }
50%{background-image:url('2.jpg'); }
55%{background-image:url('2.jpg'); }
60%{background-image:url('2.jpg'); }
70%{background-image:url('3.jpg');}
75%{background-image:url('3.jpg');}
80%{background-image:url('3.jpg');}
85%{background-image:url('4.jpg');}
90%{background-image:url('4.jpg');}
95%{background-image:url('4.jpg');}
100%{background-image:url('4.jpg');}
}
```

Comment: Certain browsers have limited support for CSS3. See http://caniuse.com/css-animation for specifics on this. Make sure the browser you are testing on supports it.

Comment: I do have the compatible version but it won't run?